# PFSense CSR Generation

Tags: linux, ssl, firewall, pfsense

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a CSR so I can generate and install a SSL cert.

Here's a [link](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=7401.0;prev_next=prev) to what I've what tried. Granted that post was for m0n0wall, but I figured openssl is openssl.

Heres where I get stuck.

When I run this:

```
/usr/bin/openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mycsr.csr -config /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I get this:

```
error on line -1 of /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
54934:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:122:fopen('/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf','rb')
54934:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:125:
54934:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:197:
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the error has something to do with the "no such file" part of the error that gets repeated a couple times, I'm just not sure how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Ernie: I've tried to edit the formatting so we can better read the error messages, but I have a bad feeling some of the formatting has still been lost.  Could you check and maybe improve it further, so we can see what you saw, CRs and all?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf exists?

Comment: All of the info is there, its a bit out of order. I'll try and correct it in a sec. And no, that file doesn't exist. I don't have a /usr/local/ssl directory listed there.

Comment: Ok, thats what I see when I run that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines are complaining about the absence of `openssl.cnf`.  My openssl, which works fine, does the same thing when I point it at a non-existent config file.  Could you try again without the `-config` stuff, and see how it goes?

Comment: Looks like that may have done it. I'll apply for the cert now and let you know shortly.

Comment: Side note, this did resolve it. Box ran great until last week, the PFSense appliance overheated and literally melted the case and partially deformed the linux server mounted on the rack beneath it.

Comment: Feedback after *six years* - seriously, *thank you* for remembering to come and let us know how it worked out after all that time!  My commiserations on the recent loss of your server(s), though :-(